# (Null) Values in SSAS cube when selecting a role

Tags: sql-server, ssas, security-roles

I have the following problem:

When I process a cube in SSAS and view the data as a normal user without restrictions all is well and the aggregated results show their normal values.

When I choose inside Data Tools (MsSQL 2012) to view the data as a specific role then all the security constraints work normally (For example I view only the Specific country data and no other) but all the corresponding values are (null).

I have tried Visual Totals = true and I have imposed those restrictions on both the dimension and the cube. The CALCULATE in calculation script is still there (everything works ok when I choose to use a normal user).

This is happening on both the measures and the calculated values!!!

Any ideas what could be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solved.**

This problem had to do with **cell data**!!!

The Data Tools studio **automatically checks** the **enable Cell Data permissions** checkboxes in the respective tab.

If no MDX query is defined in these, then it is automatically assumed that you have no permissions to view any aggregated measure data!!!!

***Uncheck them*** or ***define*** the proper ***MDX query*** and the problem will be fixed!!!!

Comment: Thanks for following up.  Current version calls this check box "Enable read permissions" which is very misleading.  It should NOT be checked if you want them to be able to read cell data.